# Looking for Dataset on Car Reliability for Predictive Modeling

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, research, australia, reliability

Hello Stack Exchange community,

I hope this post finds you well. I am currently working on a project focused on predicting car reliability using machine learning techniques. To achieve this, I am in need of a comprehensive dataset that includes information such as car specifications, maintenance history, and reliability ratings.

If anyone knows of a dataset or has access to one that could be suitable for this purpose, I would greatly appreciate your assistance. Ideally, the dataset should cover a diverse range of car models and include relevant features for predictive modeling.

I m currently working with car-vehicle-claims dataset which is not proving to be a good idea

I have checked popular platforms such as UCI Machine Learning Repository and Kaggle, but if there are any lesser-known sources or specific datasets that you've come across, please share the information or provide guidance on where I might find them.

Additionally, if there are any open automotive data initiatives or government agencies that release datasets related to car reliability and performance, I would be interested in exploring those as well.

Thank you in advance for your help, and I look forward to any suggestions or insights the community may have.